# Visual studio 2008 autorecover directory location change

Tags: visual-studio, file, recover

using vs2008 C#

Does anyone know how change the directory location that auto recover files are saved to in visual studio sp1. The specific directory it should be on my C# drive in my documents is always empty even when the feature is turned on.
There where some changes to our network env and it seems my auto recover files are now being mapped to network drive and i need to change it back.

I cant find anything on how to do this on net searches if anyone can help please.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 4):

I think that they are in the following registry setting:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0

Comment: Im sorry to say i dont know what that means ?

Comment: Tho i have to say i need it to not map to a network drive i need to change the location to make sure they are save only on my local drive